# How to delete multiple records using check_box_tag and link_to - Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

In my routes I have

```
delete 'boshu_hombu/delete_data', :as => :delete_data
```

In my controller, the delete method

```
def delete_data
  if params[:boshus]
    BoshuHombu.where(id: params[:boshus]).destroy_all
  end  
  redirect_to edit_all_path
end
```

In my views I am selecting multiple records for delete using checkbox, I have a button to invoke delete action

```
<%= link_to '削除',  { action: :delete_data}, method: :delete,
 data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, :class => 'btn btn-danger' %>
<% @get_boshu_data.each do |user| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= check_box_tag "boshus[]", user.id %></td>
    <td><%= user.id %></td>
    <td><%= user.kyujin_site %></td>
  <tr/>
<% end %>
```

but how to get the selected values in my controller's `delete_data` action. How to go about this ? thank you

Comment: Is there a reason why you need a link rather than a form? It seems that you should be using `form_tag` and then your controller code will work fine as is.

Comment: I know, but for some reasons I can not use form here. Can you think of an alternative ?

Comment: I think you're going to have to use javascript to rewrite the URL that the link submits to. The problem being that as it's a `:delete` link, rails is already going to be generating javascript to submit it as a form so I don't know how easy it will be to hook into. You may be better off just writing your own javascript altogether and taking the `method: :delete` off the link.

Comment: @TonyVincent what is the reason why you can't use form? There is a simpler way otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
<%= link_to '削除',  { action: :delete_data}, method: :delete,
 data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, :class => 'btn btn-danger', id:'delete' %>
<% @get_boshu_data.each do |user| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= check_box_tag "boshus[]", user.id, false, class: 'check' %></td>
    <td><%= user.id %></td>
    <td><%= user.kyujin_site %></td>
  <tr/>
<% end %>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 var href = $('#delete').attr('href')

 $('#delete').on('click',function(){
   var newHref = href + '?'
   $('.check').each(function(){
    if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) newHref+='boshus%5B%5D='+$(this).val()+'&'
   });
   $('#delete').attr('href',newHref)

 });

});
</script>
```

Comment: did you get something error in console ? also show me your generated link_to in html

Comment: `<a data-confirm="Are you sure?" class="btn btn-danger" id="delete" data-method="get" href="/t_arubaito_boshu_hombu/delete_data?">削除</a>` is the html generated

Comment: so whats going on after click this button ?